# change value after ajax request!

Tags: javascript, jquery

if i have 3 html pages as follows:

home.html:

```
<form method="get">        
  <input class="someForm" type="radio" value="1" name="someForm" /> Name
  <input class="someForm" type="radio" value="2" name="someForm" /> Email
  <div id="container"></div>
  <input type="submit" />
</form>

<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<script>
  var ajaxResponse = new Object();
  $(document).ready(function () {
    $('.someForm').click(function () {
    var rbVal = $(this).val();
        var myContent;
        if (ajaxResponse[rbVal]) { //in cache
          myContent =  ajaxResponse[rbVal];
          $("#container").html(myContent);
        }
        else { // not in cache
      var urlForAjaxCall = "file" + rbVal + ".html"; 
          $.get(urlForAjaxCall, function (myContent) {
             ajaxResponse[rbVal] = myContent;
             $("#container").html(myContent);
          });
        }
      });
    });
</script>
```

file1.html:

```
Name: <input type="text" name="name1" value="myName" />
```

file2.html:

```
Email: <input type="text" name="email2" value="myName@abc.com" />
```

what i want to do is that when i click (for example) radio button 1 and write something in the corresponding textbox (Name) "Alex" for example and then click whichever radio button in home.html and then reclick radio button 1 then i get the new value instead of getting "myName", any idea on how to do that?
tia

Answer (score 0):

Use PHP and then you can pass the value with a querystring or via post in your jquery...

jquery:

```
$.ajax({

   url:"file1.php",
   data:{name: $("#a_text_field_id_here").val()},
   success: function() {
     /// do something on success....
    }


});
```

ie:

```
file1.php?name=Alex
```

and your file1.php page would have something like

```
<?php 

if (isset($_GET['name'])) {
    $name = $_GET['name'];
} else {
    echo "Name is empty! do something here...";
}

?>
Name: <input type="text" name="name1" value="<? php echo $name;?>"/>
```

Most webservers have PHP now a days... and you can install it locally on your PC to test using wampserver.. which comes complete with everything... just install run and goto localhost in your browser! ... c:\wamp\www is your web directory...

Answer (score 0):

Since your going for a pure html solution here (which im assuming is the case) then you can solve it by storing data on the form on given events..

Here is a proof of concept:
http://jsfiddle.net/2Anp3/1/